# Suggest a Mutithreading approach

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a method which takes byte array and an int number as inputs and writes output extracted from array to new text file named after int number. Suppose I have 6 integers and I want to extract information from byte array for each of these integers in parallel, which multi-threading approach would you suggest?

Currently I am using async/await, but this code is taking more time compared to synchronous approach.

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    byte[] dec = File.ReadAllBytes(@"filepath");
    DateTime fdate = offset.AddDays(dateadd);
    int[] telemetry = { 1, 2, 3 };
    DateTime test1 = DateTime.Now;
    var tasks = new List<Task>();
    foreach (int tm in telemetry)
    {
        tasks.Add(RunAsync(dec, tm, fdate));
    }
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    DateTime test2 = DateTime.Now;
    draw(telemetry);
    Console.WriteLine(test2.Subtract(test1));
}

async Task RunAsync(byte[] dec, int tm, DateTime fdate)
{
    chartControl1.Series.Add(tm.ToString(), ViewType.Line);
    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"outputpath" + tm.ToString() + ".txt", true))
    {
        //DO PROCESSING
    }
}
```

Am I doing something wrong, Please suggest changes.

Comment: You can use `AsParallel().ForEach()`

Comment: What happens in "DO PROCESSING"? Note that async/await does not automatically use multiple threads. It makes the code asynchronous but not necessarily multi-threaded.

Comment: @Valentin thanks, `Parallel.ForEach()` is working for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to reduce processing time using `Parallel.ForEach() loop instead of async/await keywords. Here is sample modified code.

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
byte[] dec = File.ReadAllBytes(@"filepath");
DateTime fdate = offset.AddDays(dateadd);
int[] telemetry = { 1, 2, 3 };
DateTime test1 = DateTime.Now;
Parallel.ForEach (telemetry,tm=>
{
    using(StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("outputpath"+tm.ToString()+".txt", true))
    {
    //DO PROCESSING
    }
});
DateTime test2 = DateTime.Now;
draw(telemetry);
Console.WriteLine(test2.Subtract(test1));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can look into the TPL dataflow, might be a bit too much, but it provides a nice way to split jobs into smaller tasks with an efficient parallelization.

A nice introduction can be found here https://vimeo.com/97415351.